# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I'm getting this error, and not sure why!

I have the following form:

```
{{ Form::open( [ 'url' => 'admin/employees/store', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal' ] ) }}
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Email</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Files</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

        </div>
    </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>

  </form>
```

Which then just posts to to a controller method:

```
    public function store()
    {


    $file = Input::file('files');
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $input = Input::all();

    print_r($name);


    }
```

Which I just want print out the image that was uploaded for the minute, but the above error keeps showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a "multi" file upload field - so the file input will be an array

```
$allFiles = Input::file('files');
foreach ($allFiles as $file)
{
     print_r($file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

Comment: Try dd(Input::all()) - are the files even there?

Comment: perfect - its working now. So now you can do whatever you want with $file.